# jackson jaxrs json upgrade error

Tags: maven, jackson

After updating `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` dependency from `2.4.2` to `2.7.6`, I get below error, although I never reference `JsonFormat$Feature` directly anywhere.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.2</version>
     <!-- <version>2.7.6</version> -->
</dependency>
```

> ```
> >     Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
> >     The type com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Feature cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
> > files   CustomJacksonDeserializer.java
> ```

If I change back to `2.4.2`, the error seems to be gone.

UPDATE : It looks like workspace still refers to older version and not pointing to `2.7` latest version. In the maven repository both the versions of jar are downloaded and available but when accessed `JsonFormat` source from eclipse workspace, it points to the older version.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Does CustomJacksonDeserializer.java come from your code or from jackson library ?

Comment: no custom class defined to deserialize certain objects. And there is no reference to `JsonFormat`

Comment: Can you add this class to your post ? Can you also add how you deserialize/ serialize features ? Thanks.

Comment: class added. Do you need to find the issue ?

Comment: I think you have one of your maven dependancy needs the older version and override the newest. You need to find which dependency en specify to exclude the jackson older version. Put your pom.xml, or at least all your dependencies. I can try to help you.

Comment: I found the issue with parent pom. I had overridden explicitly in this project pom and it compiles fine.